# Uploading Data to a Website from iOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ios, database, web

I am a complete noob when it comes to iOS objective-c website connectivity. I need someone to point me to the right direction on how to upload/push data (i.e. a post) to the website that my friend programmed in Ruby on Rails.

The website is using Heroku's services and is connected to a PostgreSQL database.

I figured out a way to pull data from the site using a JSON Parser (SBJson) through the following code:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSString *rawJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL]];
anNSDictionaryObject = [[parser objectWithString:rawJSON error:nil] copy];
```

I've searched all  over the place but for some reason I can't grasp how to upload data. Do I need to access the database directly? Do I need to upload the data in the same format as I pulled it?

I'm not sure if I provided enough information but any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You shouldn't have access to the database directly -- that's asking for trouble. Instead, all updates should be run through your friend's RoR application, and hopefully he can tell you which API he provided to update the data on the database. (It might have gone through significant re-working in the application to be sent to you, relational databases are fantastic for many things but typically the programs that drive them modify or re-aggregate the data in their own fashion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first ensure that the web service exposes creating or updating objects through an API (you should never need direct access to the database). Typically in REST (and Rails) the convention is to use POST for creates and PUT for updates. For example:

```
POST /user.json 
{ user: { name: "...", email: "..." } }
```

Or:

```
PUT /users/:id.json
{ user: { name: "...", email: "..." } }
```

Once you have this setup on your server, use your JSON library to serialize out your object and an HTTP library to perform the post  on your iOS client. I recommend [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) and [HTTPRiot](https://github.com/ognen/httpriot/) as they provide a simple means to interact with RESTful servers.

Answer (score 0):

You're friend should expose a REST Api from the rails app (If you are following MVC, and even rails scaffolding, then these should be practically built in anyways).

Within the iOS app you probably want to send an asynchronous request so the main UI thread doesn't block. You'll want to create a NSMutableURLRequest with the post data and then send the data with NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Answer (score 0):

Check out StorageRoomApp they have a great service and a great support.
[Storage Room App](http://www.storageroomapp.com)